# What is the correct way to add commitlint to the commit-msg hook in husky?

Tags: node.js, commit, husky

I have an angular project where I want to enforce conventional commits. I have not been able to successfully had the right hook to prevent incorrect hooks.

I started with [this tutorial](https://www.mokkapps.de/blog/how-to-automatically-generate-a-helpful-changelog-from-your-git-commit-messages/), where it said to add the following to package.json:

```
{
  "hooks": {
    "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
  }
}
```

This did not work (it still let in bad commits) so I did some research and found [this article](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2019/05/29/git-husky-commitlint/) where it said that the above is for husky 4, and for husky 5 I should run this command:

```
npx husky add .husky/commit-msg 'npx commitlint --edit $1'
```

From what I can tell, the [commitlint official docs](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/blob/master/docs/guides-local-setup.md#install-husky) say to do it the same way. However, when I run it, I get this strange prompt that does not do anything:

```
PS C:\...\MyProj> npx husky add .husky/commit-msg 'npx --no-install commitlint --edit $1'
Usage
  husky install [dir] (default: .husky)
  husky uninstall
  husky set|add <file> [cmd]
```

This is just confusing, because what I have written actually follows the third line of the prompt.

Has anyone been through this and can help me understand what I need to do?

Relevant parts from package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "husky install"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^12.1.1",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^12.1.1",
    "husky": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like there was an issue running `npx husky add .husky/commit-msg 'npx --no-install commitlint --edit $1'` because the command part was more than one word. A workaround I found was to split it up into two parts.

1 - Call `npx husky add .husky/commit-msg`

This created an empty/ default file in the right place with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

undefined
```

2 - Then I just replaced `undefined` with  `npx --no-install commitlint --edit $1` and it works

[This part of the commitlint docs](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=husky_git_params-ie-commitlint-) helped me understand that doing it that way was okay

Hope this helps anyone else who encounters the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

You are using Windows. So, try this (it worked for me)

```
npx husky add .husky/commit-msg "npx --no-install commitlint --edit "$1""
```

with double quotes instead. Note that $1 also needs double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i forgot to install those 2 npm packages:

- @commitlint/cli
- @commitlint/config-conventional

After installing them `npm i -D @commitlint/cli @commitlint/config-conventional` the problem was solved.